# NetSuiteService class not found in .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, netsuite, .net-standard-2.0

I have a legacy code base to connect with Oracle NetSuite `https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2017_1_0/netsuite.wsdl` in .NET Framework project. Now I have to migrate the code base to a .NET Core Standard 2.0 project.

After I have added the same `wsdl` reference as a `Connected Service`, it generates the `Reference.cs` file, but it does not contains the `NetSuiteService` class.

I have tried to change codes to make it working but so far no luck. Can anyone help me to figure out how to connect with NetSuite from .NET Core code base OR a good reference.

Comment: Hi, Did you find an answer for above issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find an answer as I remember, and I'm not with the project now.

Comment: Here is a promising link:
https://medium.com/@benwmills/using-the-netsuite-suitetalk-api-with-net-core-net-standard-40f1a4464da1